# How to execute threads with ExecutorService in concrete order?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In my program I have several commands, which are performed by commands executor class. I need to execute 4 command one by one in order(not to show users before I create a new one), using ExecutorService.

Execution environment:

```
public class ConcurrentCommandExecutionEnvironment {
    private static final int POOL_SIZE = 4;

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConcurrentCommandExecutionEnvironment.class);

    public void readArgsAndExecuteCommand(String[] props) {
        if (props.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: no params entered");
        }

        ExecutorService execService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                4,
                4,
                0L,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
        );
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        CommandStore commandStore = new CommandStore();
        CommandExecutor commandExecutor = new CommandExecutor(
                new CreateUserCommand(commandStore),
                new GetUserListCommand(commandStore),
                new CreateTaskCommand(commandStore),
                new GetTasksListCommand(commandStore),
                new GetTaskByUsernameCommand(commandStore),
                new CompleteTaskCommand(commandStore),
                new DeleteUserCommand(commandStore),
                new CreateUserAndTaskCommand(commandStore)
        );

        execService.execute(() -> {                
                commandExecutor.createUserAndTask(props);           
        });

        execService.execute(() -> {               
                commandExecutor.getUsers(props);
        });

        execService.execute(() -> {                
                commandExecutor.getTasks(props);           
        });

        execService.shutdown();
}
```

Previously I didn't work with ExecutorService and synchronized threads using "synchronized" operator.
Can I use it here like this(to use commandExecutor instance as mutex and to synchronize on it in every thread like in example below):

```
execService.execute(() -> {
            synchronized (commandExecutor) {
                commandExecutor.createUserAndTask(props);
      }
  });
```

Or with ExecutorService I should proceed in another way?

Comment: You could just use a [singleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--). You don't need 4 threads to run things sequentially. In fact the whole name of the class is misleading if you're not actually running things concurrently.

Comment: By the way, after calling shutdown, you need to call `awaitTermination` to give time for submitted tasks to complete. In the future with Project Loom technology, the executor service interface will support `Closeable`, so we can use try-with-resources syntax to more conveniently, concisely, and automatically do this shutdown-and-wait operation.

Comment: I'm just wondering, why you want to use ExecutorService if you need to execute all the code sequentually, step by step, command by command but not concurrently? BTW, for more flexible scheduling you may look into Phaser https://www.baeldung.com/java-phaser

Comment: @AnatolyG  such task I got from mentor. this is a kind of training in order to understand how to synchronize threads in executor pool. of course it should be done in a way, which is described here, but I want to understand executor's synchronization

Comment: The whole concept of synchronizing order of operation in threads is misguided.  The whole point of threads is that they can work mostly asynchronously for maximum concurrency.  I see these sorts of programming assignments all of the time and they are infuriating.  No one does this in an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't interested in the natural sequential execution with the `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` or even without the `ExecutorService` at all :)... Then let's look at the simplified illustration what the `ExecutorService` is (`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)`):

```
final BlockingQueue<Runnable> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

final int nThreads = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                tasks.take().run();
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                break;
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

tasks.offer(() -> System.out.println("Task 1"));
tasks.offer(() -> System.out.println("Task 2"));
tasks.offer(() -> System.out.println("Task 3"));
```

As you can see, there is no out-of-the-box tooling for inter-task/thread synchronization/communication. We cannot manage threads directly, but we can manage our tasks and this will affect the thread execution. For instance:

1. Submit the next task after the previous one is finished. This is a quite natural solution and sometimes it is very useful (especially for scheduled execution). You submit/schedule a task until a condition is true. Do your logic, check the condition, submit/schedule the next task if the condition is true. This naturally guarantees that you have only one task running at a time (with any type of Executor). Here is an example of how it could be done:

```
    public class CommandChain implements Runnable {
        public static CommandChain start(final ExecutorService executor, final Runnable command) {
            return new CommandChain(executor, command);
        }

        private final ExecutorService executor;
        private final Runnable command;
        private CommandChain then;

        private CommandChain(final ExecutorService executor, final Runnable command) {
            this.executor = executor;
            this.command = command;
        }

        public CommandChain then(final Runnable command) {
            then = new CommandChain(this.executor, command);
            return then;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            command.run();
            if (then != null) {
                executor.submit(then);
            }
        }
    }

    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    final CommandChain command1 = CommandChain.start(executor, () -> System.out.println("Command 1"));
    command1.then(() -> System.out.println("Command 2"))
            .then(() -> System.out.println("Command 3"));
    executor.submit(command1);
```

This trick works with any type of ExecutorService, including pooled with any pool size or just `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`

2. In a task wait until the previous one is finished and notify the next task when this particular one is done. One of the most convenient ways for such 1-to-1 waiting/notification is using the `CountDownLatch`:

```
    public class CommandChain implements Runnable {
        public static CommandChain start(final Runnable command) {
            return new CommandChain(null, command);
        }

        private final CountDownLatch waitLatch;
        private final Runnable command;

        private CommandChain then;

        private CommandChain(final CountDownLatch waitLatch, final Runnable command) {
            this.waitLatch = waitLatch;
            this.command = command;
        }

        public CommandChain then(final Runnable command) {
            then = new CommandChain(new CountDownLatch(1), command);
            return then;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (waitLatch != null) {
                try {
                    waitLatch.await();
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return; // we are here, because 
                    // ExecutorService is stopping with
                    // interruption of its workers, so
                    // let's finish the execution
                }
            }
            command.run();
            if (then != null) {
                then.waitLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    final CommandChain command1 = CommandChain.start(() -> System.out.println("Command 1"));
    final CommandChain command2 = command1.then(() -> System.out.println("Command 2"));
    final CommandChain command3 = command2.then(() -> System.out.println("Command 3"));

    // the order doesn't matter
    executor.submit(command3);
    executor.submit(command1);
    executor.submit(command2);
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that you should have enough threads to execute all tasks in the worst case of blocking/awaiting - from end to start of the chain - when the last command calls `waitLatch.await()` first, then the command before the last one calls its await and so on... This means **n(umber)Threads >= n(umber)Tasks**. Otherwise, the execution can stop, just try `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` for this example.

We also can manage the order of task/command execution outside (in the main thread, for example) with the same shared `CountDownLatch`es or `CyclicBarrier`s, `Phaser` etc.

Answer (score 5):

## `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`

If you need multiple tasks to be run sequentially, submit them to a [single-threaded executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()).

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
…
es.submit( task1 ) ;
es.submit( task2 ) ;
es.submit( task3 ) ;
```

---

Or reconsider if you even need the executor service at all. If the original thread waits for the series of tasks to run sequentially in a single-threaded executor service, the original thread could just as well run the tasks itself. If waiting on a single thread, there is no point to being threaded.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I need to understand pool threads synchronizing. so I need solution with a thread-pool