# Which threading mechanism to use for tasks that enqueue other tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I'm using a task that creates other tasks. Those tasks in turn may or may not create subsequent tasks. I don't know beforehand how many tasks will be created in total. At some point, no more tasks will be created, and all the task will finish.

When the last task is done, I must do some extra stuff.

Which threading mechanism should be used? I've read about [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), [Cyclic Barrier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) and [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) but none seem to fit.

I've also tried using [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), but I've encountered some issues such as the inability to execute something at the end, and you can see my attempt below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

public class Issue {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    var count = new AtomicInteger(1);
    var executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    class Task implements Runnable {
      final int id = count.getAndIncrement();
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          MILLISECONDS.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1000L + 1000L));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // Do nothing
        }
        if (id < 5) {
          executor.submit(new Task());
          executor.submit(new Task());
        }
        System.out.println(id);
      }
    }
    executor.execute(new Task());
    executor.shutdown();
//    executor.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

This outputs an exception because tasks are added after `shutdown()` is called, but the expected output would be akin to:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Hello
```

Which threading mechanism can help me do that?

Comment: If you need to execute tasks one by one to have the total order (no any parallelization), look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421884/how-to-execute-threads-with-executorservice-in-concrete-order/67441030#67441030 If you are looking for more flexible way to parallelize tasks, you might enchance the previous example or take a look at ForkJoinPool http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/java-fork-and-join-forkjoinpool.html

Comment: @AnatolyG I don't want sequential: only multithreaded, I hinted at it with the tags "multithreading" and "concurrency". Also, the ForkJoinPool doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I believe a good start might be to define what does "the last" task mean exactly? What's the formal rule?

Comment: @AnatolyG The relevant part is not "the last", but the whole preposition: "When the last task is done": that basically means when every "`Task`" has finished executing their own statements and there are no more `Task` in the queue.

Comment: "No more Task in the queue" - isn't enough, I'm afraid. For example, you are going to schedule/execute 10 tasks in a loop and sometimes the new task is executed faster than you put a next task into the queue. You have the queue empty for a few micro/milliseconds, but the task we've just executed isn't really "last" right? "No more tasks in the queue for a timeout" may work but also seems to be odd... Can we say when we stop adding for sure?

Comment: You use a timeout on empty queue OR, better, you have/know a condition when you stop adding new tasks in the queue and after the condition is true you wait until the queue is empty and then you do your "extra stuff"

Comment: To understand "the queue is empty" you may use different solutions. "executor.getTaskCount() == executor.getCompletedTaskCount()" as suggested below or to increment shared AtomicInteger before scheduling a task and decrement in the end of the task and wait until the counter is 0 etc.etc.

Comment: @AnatolyG any means is good as long as I'm sure that the queue is empty. All your suggestions are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty tricky. If there is even a single task that's either in the queue or currently executing, then since you can't say whether or not it will spawn another task, you have no way to know how long it may run for. It may be the start of a chain of tasks that takes another 2 hours.

I think all the information you'd need to achieve this is encapsulated by the executor implementations. You need to know what's running and what's in the queue.

I think you're unfortunately looking at having to write your own executor. It needn't be complicated and it doesn't have to conform to the JDK's interfaces if you don't want it to. Just something that maintains a thread pool and a queue of tasks. Add the ability to attach listeners to the executor. When the queue is empty and there are no actively executing tasks then you can notify the listeners.

Here's a quick code sketch.

```
class MyExecutor
{
    private final AtomicLong taskId = new AtomicLong();
    private final Map<Long, Runnable> idToQueuedTask = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final AtomicLong runningTasks  = new AtomicLong();
    private final ExecutorService delegate = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public void submit(Runnable task) {
        long id = taskId.incrementAndGet();
        final Runnable wrapped = () -> {
            taskStarted(id);
            try {
                task.run();
            }
            finally {
                taskEnded();
            }
        };
        idToQueuedTask.put(id, wrapped);
        delegate.submit(wrapped);
    }
    
    private void taskStarted(long id) {
        idToQueuedTask.remove(id);
        runningTasks.incrementAndGet();
    }
    
    private void taskEnded() {
        final long numRunning = runningTasks.decrementAndGet();
        if (numRunning == 0 && idToQueuedTask.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Done, time to notify listeners");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyExecutor executor = new MyExecutor();
        executor.submit(() -> {
            System.out.println("Parent task");
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
            
            executor.submit(() -> {
                System.out.println("Child task");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I kind of wanted to avoid this, hoping for an existing framework inside the JDK, but if there's none, so be it!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I realised since writing this that if you wrap the tasks then you can delegate almost everything to an existing ExecutorService, see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `ExecutorService` to this:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

You could then use the count functions to wait:

```
    while(executor.getTaskCount() > executor.getCompletedTaskCount())
    {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10L);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Hello");
```

Comment: This is not what I expected, but it pretty much solves everything I've been struggling to for the past week. It seems so simple in retrospect! Thanks :)

Comment: Multiple things are not great about this. The unchecked cast, the docs for both of those methods saying "*the returned value is only an approximation*", the fact the thread is blocked [busy-waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) (the smaller the value is, the more cycles you're wasting. the larger the value, the larger the gap between them being done and running the finalizer code)

Comment: @Michael yes, I know. The unchecked cast can be replaced by a direct call of the content of the `Exceutors.newFixedThreadPool` method. The count methods are an approximation because there _could_ be a task added from outside. In this case it's not that relevant because the new tasks get added inside an active task.