# Example where Java lock works but synchronisation doesn't

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, synchronized

I have been looking into scenarios where using Lock, ReentrantLock fits perfectly fine, but that scenario would be unachievable by using usual synchronisation. The official javadocs says:

> There are occasions where you need to work with locks in a more
> flexible way. For example, some algorithms for traversing concurrently
> accessed data structures require the use of "hand-over-hand" or "chain
> locking": you acquire the lock of node A, then node B, then release A
> and acquire C, then release B and acquire D and so on. Implementations
> of the Lock interface enable the use of such techniques by allowing a
> lock to be acquired and released in different scopes, and allowing
> multiple locks to be acquired and released in any order.

I failed to find any such example code snippet where only ReentrantLock solved the problem, but not the usual synchronization. I am aware of all the other advantages that Lock interfaces provide such as fairness, etc., but I am not looking for the theories.

Comment: I think the paragraph talks about the fact that methods of Lock interface could be called anytime and anywhere as long as you have a reference to an instance of that interface but synchronized(lock){} acquires the lock before entry and releases the lock after action in {}  performed. You could use lock interface to release the lock in the middle of {}. [in the middle of some action].

Comment: Well, technically, you *can* just slap `synchronized` all over the place and be thread-safe that way, but you don't get much fine-grained control like that, do you? What if you want more fine-grained locking, so that the code can run in parallel as much as possible?

Comment: Probably, database transactions works that way. [When deadlock occurs and database systems detect that. The database should cancel some transactions so that the deadlock is fixed. (The cancelled transactions tried again). In this case, some in the middle of an action release of a lock would be required.] A transaction might acquire multiple locks. [a lock is used for whole table or a row of a table]

Comment: The docs already mentioned "hand-over-hand" locking, so how about looking that up first? :)

Comment: What is unclear about the description of _""hand-over-hand" or "chain locking""_? That is something like _lock1.lock, do something, lock2.lock, lock1.unlock, do something, lock2.unlock_. You can't do that with synchronized. Or are you specifically looking for a code sample that does that because you can imagine why or how that would work?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Do you have a sample snippet for that(lock1.lock, do something, lock2.lock, lock1.unlock, do something, lock2.unlock)? I will try to achieve that using just synchronized and won't use lock.

Comment: @Deca the problem of synchronized is that it has its own scope, so if you need sequential locking, the only way is to use inner synchronized block. For example synchronized (a) { synchronized (b) {}}. Inner blocks have only one single order of monitor locking {a, b} and, obviously, only one single order of unlocking {b, a}, never {a, b}. I've updated my answer with this

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the case that a simple `synchronize` was no longer sufficient. It should be ensured that a long running job like a data import should not run in parallel. But if, for some reason, a second job would be started this second job should be blocked until the first job ends. Really simple. But because such a case would be an error situation in our system, there should be a log message in case of blocking. For this use case we need more than a simple `synchronize`.

We used the `ReentrantLock`'s `tryLock()` method to implement this.

Here a simplified version of our implementation:

The job has to implement the interface `ProtectedExecutable` with the critical section in method `execute()` and blocking handler in `onBlocking()`.

```
interface ProtectedExecutable {
  /**
   * The code to be executed as a critical section
   * @return Result value
   */
  int execute();

  /**
   * Is called only if the execution was blocked.
   * @param reason Text with the blocking reason, which can be logged. Contains the description of the blocking ProtectedExecutable if
   *               possible
   */
  void onBlocking(String reason);
}
```

In ProtectedExecutor `tryLock()` is first used to enter the critical section or to return `false` if it is blocked. So there is a chance to do some action before calling the blocking version `lock()` and wait.

```
class ProtectedExecutor {
  private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  public int execute(ProtectedExecutable executable) {
    if(lock.tryLock()) {
      try{
        return executable.execute();
      } finally {
        lock.unlock();
      }
    } else {
      executable.onBlocking("Execution blocked by another ProtectedExecutor!");
      lock.lock();
      try {
        return executable.execute();
      } finally {
        lock.unlock();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can `ReentrantLock` be naive/directly replaced by `synchronized` in all cases? -No. Just because the locking with `ReentrantLock` can cross method/block scope, and locking with `synchronized` cannot, it sets its own scope (at least you have to re-invent the lock with wait/notify(All) to have the same feature). What does it mean? For two locks `a` and `b` the `ReentrantLock` allows you to have any order of locking and any order of unlocking. For example, `lock {a, b}`, `unlock {a, b}` or `unlock {b, a}`. The `synchronized` block allows the order of unlocking to be only reverse order of locking (`synchronized (a) { synchronized (b) {}}` - `lock {a, b}`, `unlock {b, a}`, *never* `unlock {a, b}`)

But, all practical problems can be resolved without `ReentrantLock`. And here I'd like to share some thoughts...

Most samples/comments will show how to use `ReentrantLock` to solve a problem, but in most cases there is another solution, and it may be even simpler, more clear, more natural. For example, "chain locking" tries to solve the problem of specific sequence of execution. This particular problem can be resolved with appropriate `ExecutorService` (for example with a single threaded executor for sequential execution) and a set of Tasks we put in specific order to be executed. More complex cases can be addressed with something like `java.util.concurrent.Phaser` etc. Or, there is another trick: to schedule next task(s) to be executed in the end of the current one ([How to execute threads with ExecutorService in concrete order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421884/how-to-execute-threads-with-executorservice-in-concrete-order/67441030#67441030)). Threads and queues (mostly blocking) are very-very power, natural and canonical way to orchestrate multithreading work, and that way is significantly more safe, than locking.

For example, "chain locking" is deadlock-prone if different chains may have different order. Compare "*lock1.lock, do something, lock2.lock, lock1.unlock, do something, lock2.unlock*" and "*lock2.lock, do something, lock1.lock, lock2.unlock, do something, lock1.unlock*". So, I would recommend to avoid "chain locking" in real design, if possible. The same for classic nested `synchronized` blocks.

Another example when a task "should not run in parallel" (`ProtectedExecutable` below) also perfectly can be resolved (by design) with a single threaded executor, and so on.

Then why we may prefer `ReentrantLock` over `synchronized` in our day-to-day practice?...

There is a known small difference in terms of performance between synchronized and `ReentrantLock` in cases of high contention, but not sure that's really important somewhere out of synthetic tests on specific JDK (Java 15 have disabled biased locking (JEP 374) in the Java virtual machine and this can affect test results).

I'd say that the only thing I've found useful in my personal practice is design-related, and it bases on the fact that *with a lock we can cross method scope*. This is not about a problem which can be resolved with `ReentrantLock` only, but about a case when it may be convenient to use it. When you need a thread safe structure/class with a more or less complex behavior, there are 2 main patterns:

```
// each thread-safe business method is atomic
// and synchronized
class A {
  // a lot of fields here

  private void doX() {
    // a portion of manipulations with the fields
  }
  private void doY() {
    // another portion of manipulations with the fields
  }

  public synchronized void threadSafeOperation() {
     doX();
     doY();
  }
}

A a = new A();
a.threadSafeOperation();


// each thread-safe business method is atomic
// and synchronized
class A {
  private final ReenterantLock lock = new ReenterantLock();
  // a lot of fields here

  public void lock() {
    lock.lock();
  }

  public void unlock() {
    lock.unlock();
  }

  public void doX() {
    // a portion of manipulations with the fields
  }
  public void doY() {
    // another portion of manipulations with the fields
  }
}

A a = new A();
a.lock();
try {
  a.doX();
  a.doY();
} finally {
  a.unlock();
}
```

The first pattern requires each thread-safe operation/usage to be defined as one single synchronized method. The second pattern allows you to use different combinations in different use cases. Each one may be reasonable/preferable in specific case.

In the second case we also may say "use synchronized instead of lock", but specifically and explicitly defined lock/unlock operations say more about our intentions and rules of usage than:

```
A a = new A();
synchronized(a) {
  a.doX();
  a.doY();
}
```

Java object monitor's based synchronization (`synchronized` + `wait` + `notify(All)`) helped to resolve all practical problems for years, but one day Doug Lea and Co had decided to develop a rich, object-oriented library of concurrent primitives. So, now we have a number of more or less useful locks, things like `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` (instead of `wait` + `notify(All)`), effective concurrent collections and some other stuff. Now we can choose more expressive, effective way/tool to solve our day-to-day problems in concurrency.